# Are arrays zero indexed when they are passed throu functions as arguments? C programming

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Are array zero indexed when they are passed throu an function as argument? Or did C just copy the array A's memory into two different arrays?

I never need to "reset" the orginal position of an array when I pass the same array throu another function?

```
static const int A[3] = {1, 5, 8};

void fun(const int B[]){
    printf("val = %d\n", *B);
    B++;
    printf("val = %d\n", *B);
}

int main() {

    fun(A);
    fun(A);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
val = 1
val = 5
val = 1
val = 5
```

For example when I don't use `const`, I can see that they share the same memory, but that'only when I don't use `const`.

```
static int A[3] = {1, 5, 8};

void fun(int B[]){
    printf("val = %d\n", *B);
    *B = 10;
    printf("val = %d\n", *B);
}

int main() {

    fun(A);
    fun(A);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
val = 1
val = 10
val = 10
val = 10
```

Comment: Arrays are always 0 indexed. `B++;` however only modifies a local pointer, it doesn't change anything within the array `B` points to

Comment: @UnholySheep So that menas that I never ever need to "reset" the array if I want to pass it to another function? :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "reset" - `B` is a pointer local to the function, it never is visible outside of it. Presumably the answer you are looking for is "yes", although it's hard to tell since you seem to have a wrong understanding of what an "array parameter" does

Comment: @UnholySheep Reset = Starting of the index. E.g B[0].

Comment: That statement doesn't make sense as you cannot change at what index an array starts to begin with. Every array starts at index 0

Comment: The title makes no sense. Arrays *cannot* be passed to functions as an argument in C programming language ( unless they are embedded in a struct or union).

Comment: "Zero-indexed" means that `array[0]` accesses the first element from whatever array is. (`array[i]` is syntactic sugar for `*(array + i)`.) Whether array is a function argument does not affect that.

Comment: But I don't create a new array in example 1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You modify local pointer. Why pointer? Because array are passed as pointers. To modify the original pointer you need to pass pointer to pointer

```
int A[] = {1, 5, 8, 10};

void fun(const int **B){
    printf("val = %d\n", **B);
    (*B)++;
    printf("val = %d\n", **B);
}

int main() 
{
    int *C = A;
    fun(&C);
    fun(&C);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `func(&C);`?

Comment: @UnholySheep of course . SO should invest in some code editor.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson don't you see the difference?

Comment: It remembers the index?

Comment: First you create a array `C` from `A` and then pass the...address? to the function `fun`. And `**` means?

Comment: I don't understand why this answer will answer my question? I don't want to modify, or create a new array. Just be sure that the index does not move the complete array. @UnholySheep explained that when I pass the same array trhrou the function again, then the index is in the normal posiiton again, e.g. 0.

Comment: Ć is not an array

Comment: Do I create a new address of `A` at my first example?